# How to use --commit-filter to exclude 20 commit in one git filter-branch pass?

Tags: git, bash, git-filter-branch

I need to clean 20 commits in a row from git history in bare repository.
I try to use the following command, (notice, i do not want to write full-length hashes and try to use sub-string comparison):

```
git filter-branch -d /dev/shm/scratch --commit-filter '
 if [ ${GIT_COMMIT0:7} = e687d59 ] ||
    [ ${GIT_COMMIT0:7} = 58daf29 ] ||
    ...
    [ ${GIT_COMMIT0:7} = 682b2c2 ] ||
    [ ${GIT_COMMIT0:7} = 947db9e ];
    then
            skip_commit "$@";
    else
            git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

But i instantly get message like:

> Rewrite 414840693169a74d052548c7a7a1bc5b06d3b79c (1/10360) (0 seconds
>   passed, remaining 0 predicted)    git commit-tree: 49: git
>   commit-tree: Bad substitution could not write rewritten commit

There is somweting wrong either with OR condition or with sub-strings, i can't figure out.

I also have additional question: how can i get log file with mapping old hash to a new one when `git filter-branch` completed it's job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that this:

> ```
> if [ ${GIT_COMMIT0:7} = e687d59 ] ||
>    [ ${GIT_COMMIT0:7} = 58daf29 ] ||
>    ...
>    [ ${GIT_COMMIT0:7} = 682b2c2 ] ||
>    [ ${GIT_COMMIT0:7} = 947db9e ];
> ```

is wrong.

The bash syntax for substrings is `${name:offset:length}`, which in this case would be `${GIT_COMMIT:0:7}`, i.e., you are missing a colon.

But:

- `git filter-branch` is an sh (not bash) script;
- the filter-branch script uses `eval`; and
- this isn't really the best way to do this anyway.

The first two mean that you cannot rely on bash-specific syntax here.

The third means that there's no real reason to do so.

One option is to use the `-o` (or) operator of the `[` (aka `test`) program:

```
if [ $GIT_COMMIT = ... -o
     $GIT_COMMIT = ... -o
     ...
     $GIT_COMMIT = ... ]; then
```

but that's still too painful, in my opinion.  Instead, why not use `grep`, e.g.:

```
if echo $GIT_COMMIT | grep -F -f /tmp/list >/dev/null; then
```

where the file `/tmp/list` contains the IDs you want to skip?  If grep finds one of them, it exits with a zero (success) status, otherwise it exits with a nonzero (failure) status, the same way the `test` or `[` program exits 0 if the test succeeds, or nonzero if it fails.

(If your grep has `-q`, you can use that rather than redirecting to `/dev/null`.)

Comment: grep -f filename.txt along with commit-filter returns a No such file or directory error. Any idea ? I am new to shell scripting

Comment: @faizi: That one has nothing to do with bash, and everything to do with Git: a `--commit-filter` is run without checking out any existing commits. The filters all run in a private subdirectory that `git filter-branch` makes. The only files present here are files that Git has created for itself, or, if you use `--tree-filter`, the tree that Git extracted for your filter to operate on—tree filters are different from all other filter-branch filters.

Comment: So what about `/tmp/list` ? is this file created by git ? I am try to execute something like this. 
`if [ 'git rev-list --all | grep -cf logfile.txt' -gt 0 ]` where `logfile.txt` contains a number of commit messages, that I wish to filter

Comment: `/tmp/list` would be a file *you* create *before* you run `git filter-branch`. You would put into it a list of commit hash IDs that you want *your commands* to act upon. You then supply *your commands* as the argument to one of the `--filter-*` arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Git Bash, so where should I keep my file in windows ( instead of `/tmp`) ?  Kindly correct me if I am saying something blunder.

Comment: @faizi: I don't use Windows and therefore don't know, but it seems like /tmp should still work fine there. Still, put the file wherever you like, just remember that `git filter-branch` runs your commands in a location chosen by filter-branch, so you cannot use relative pathnames.

Answer (score 3):

I would write it as

```
git filter-branch -d /dev/shm/scratch --commit-filter '
    case $GIT_COMMIT in
    e687d59*|58daf29*|682b2c2*|947db9e*)
        skip_commit "$@"
        ;;
    *)
        git commit-tree "$@"
        ;;
    esac' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

It is not vastly better than your statement (after you have fixed it as pointed out), but still a bit less typing.

If you know a commit before those being rewritten, it would probably pay off to add it like so:

```
... --tag-name-filter cat -- --all --not that_commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things to try - I haven't had this situation myself, so have not tested any of them.

1. The substrings should be `${GIT_COMMIT:0:7}` rather than `${GIT_COMMIT0:7}` (colon after the variable name)
2. Instead of `--tag-name-filter cat -- --all`, use `HEAD`.  The [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) gives a relevant example:

   > To remove commits authored by "Darl McBribe" from the history:
   >
   > ```
   > git filter-branch --commit-filter '
   >        if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "Darl McBribe" ];
   >        then
   >                skip_commit "$@";
   >        else
   >                git commit-tree "$@";
   >        fi' HEAD
   > ```

   ```
                ^^^^
   ```

   Note that specifying `HEAD` is enough to clean the repository in that example.
3. Use the `bash` tests instead of `test(1)` (should be faster, and is more robust):

   ```
   if [[ ${GIT_COMMIT0:7} = e687d59  ||  ${GIT_COMMIT0:7} = 58daf29 || ... ]]; then
   ```

Comment: Just using `HEAD` is bad if there are other branches that branch off _after_ the rewritten history.

Comment: @j6t Thanks for the tip